# Duvida de posicionamento

Tags: html, css, flexbox, posicionamento

Estou com uma duvida de posicionamento, gostaria de passar apenas a option2 para a direita sem que o espaçamento entre label e option 1 fosse alterado, estou usando um container com flexbox.

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  
  height:200px;
  background:gold;
  padding:20px;
}
.title,.item{
  padding:20px;
  background:tomato;
  margin:10px;
}
.title{
  width:60%;
}
.item{
  height:20px;
  width:10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label class="title">Label</label>
  
  <div class="item">Option 1</div>

  <div class="item">Option 2</div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: Não posso alterar a estrutura html

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então eu não consegui entender completamente qual é o resultado desejado, mas acredito que seja um dos dois.

**Situação 1: Caso você queira apenas mudar o posicionamento do elemento, sem mudar seu tamanho.**

Bom nesse caso, não consegui encontrar nenhuma propriedade de flex que pudesse ajudar. Por isso adicionei a propriedade "position: relative;" ao container o que nós posibilita ir até a div "Option 2" e adicionar as  propriedades {position:absolute; top: 20px; right:20px;}

Esse é o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E esse é o código HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <label class="title">Label</label>
  
  <div class="item">Option 1</div>

  <div class="item" id="option-2">Option 2</div>
</div>
```

E esse é o CSS:

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  
  height:200px;
  background:gold;
  padding:20px;
  position: relative;
}
.title,.item{
  padding:20px;
  background:tomato;
  margin:10px;
}
.title{
  width:60%;
}
.item{
  height:20px;
  width:10%;
}

#option-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

**Situação 2: Caso você queira esticar o item até ele colar na borda.**

Bom nesse caso, basta adicionar a propriedade "flex-grow: 1;" na div option 2.

Esse é o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o código HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <label class="title">Label</label>
  
  <div class="item">Option 1</div>

  <div class="item" id="option-2">Option 2</div>
</div>
```

Esse é o código CSS:

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  
  height:200px;
  background:gold;
  padding:20px;
}
.title,.item{
  padding:20px;
  background:tomato;
  margin:10px;
}
.title{
  width:60%;
}
.item{
  height:20px;
  width:10%;
}

#option-2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Me referia justamente a primeira situação, estava tentando resolver apenas com o flexbox, obrigado pela resposta!